# How to hide service classes and prevent @Autowire?

Tags: java, spring

I create a framework that has several default implementations for an interface.

Question: how can I hide any default implementations of the interface, so that users of the framework are forced to use the `DefaultService` interface for eg injection with `@Autowired DefaultService`?

```
interface DefaultService {
}

@Component
@Async
@ConditionalOnNotWebApplication
public class MyService1 implements DefaultService {

}

@Component
@Async
@ConditionalOnWebApplication
public class MyService2 implements DefaultService {

}
```

The conditions on my services ensure there is always only one service wired in each environment.

Comment: I think both `@Component` and `@Async` only work on a `public class`. Otherwise spring ignores them

Comment: Is the aim to force users to autowire only by interface? correct?

Comment: Yes I want to force autowire by interface and prevent injection of the implementations.

Comment: You marker both 'spring' and 'cdi' Personally i feel bad over two DI enviroments

Comment: Make the bean classes package private (i.e. remove the `public` modifier). that way the class isn't visible but spring will still detect it and instantiate it. Autowiring can still be done through the interface.

Answer (score 3):

As @M. Deinum commented above making the implementation services package private is the correct solution. I was not aware spring still sees those classes, as normally spring requires public access for annotations.

---

One possible solution seems to be creating an extra `@Configuration` class for the implementations:

```
@Configuration
public class DefaultServiceConfiguration {
    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnNotWebApplication
    public DefaultService getDefaultService1() {
        return new MyService1();
    }

    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnWebApplication
    public DefaultService getDefaultService2() {
        return new MyService2();
    }
}

public interface DefaultService {
}

@Async
protected class MyService1 {
}

@Async
protected class MyService2 {
}
```

This way only the `DefaultService` interface is visible to framework users.

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me.

**Create an Custom annotation:**

```
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

    /**
     * Created by pyaswan on 8/18/17.
     */
    @Target({ElementType.TYPE})
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    public @interface NotAutowiredBean {

    }
```

**BeanFactoryPostProcessor:**

```
import com.yaswanth.NotAutowiredBean;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationNotAllowedException;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanFactoryPostProcessor;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ConfigurableListableBeanFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

/**
 * Created by pyaswan on 8/18/17.o
 */
@Component
public class NotAutowiredBeanFactoryPostProcessor implements BeanFactoryPostProcessor {

    @Override
    public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory)
        throws BeansException {
        try {
            String[] illegalAutowiredBeans = beanFactory
                .getBeanNamesForAnnotation(NotAutowiredBean.class);

            String[] allBeans = beanFactory.getBeanDefinitionNames();

            for (String beanName : allBeans) {
                String beanClassName = beanFactory.getBeanDefinition(beanName).getBeanClassName();

                if (beanClassName != null) {
                    Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(beanClassName);
                    Field[] fields = clazz.getDeclaredFields();

                    for (Field field : fields) {
                        if (field.isAnnotationPresent(Autowired.class)) {
                            if (field.getType().isAnnotationPresent(NotAutowiredBean.class)) {
                                throw new BeanCreationNotAllowedException(beanName, "");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**Spring beans:**

```
interface DefaultService {
}

@NotAutowiredBean
@Component
@Async
@ConditionalOnNotWebApplication
public class MyService1 implements DefaultService {

}

@NotAutowiredBean
@Component
@Async
@ConditionalOnWebApplication
public class MyService2 implements DefaultService {

}
```

You need to annotate the implementations with `@NotAutowiredBean`. The `NotAutowiredBeanFactoryPostProcessor` looks through all the beans, iterates the fields which are annotated with `Autowired` annotation for each bean class. It takes the type of the field and looks for `NotAutowiredBean` annotation on the class type of the field. If present, it throws an `BeanCreationNotAllowedException` which will make the app start to fail.

Comment: While I appreciate your help, this is way more complicated than being useful in a real world app.

Comment: You just need to add this postProcessor and add the annotation on the beans you want to hide. What do you think is complicated about this?

Comment: I have to introduce an additional class (the postprocessor) explicit. depending on the project this is not always wanted, whilst it may work.